# How does NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate work?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm new with iOS (Swift) and trying to understand NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate mechanism.
What I specifically don't understand is how does NSFetchedResultsChangeType is recognized. What invokes insert/delete/update etc. actions? 
When "func controller(...)" functions are called?
I can't get it from Apple's documentation.
Please shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is not that smart. When you create it, you set a fetchedRequest and a context on it, and tell it to `performFetch`.  Once it has performed a fetch it has an array of objects that matches the predicate.  It then monitors all changes to the core data context that was passed to it.  When an object (of the same Entity type) is changed the fetchedResultsController then runs the predicate of the fetch request on the change object to decide if it should be added or removed from the list. If the object was deleted, or was in the list before, and is now not in the list then it is a `delete`.  If it was not in the list before but now it does pass the predicate then it is an `insert`.  If one of the fields that are used by the sort descriptor is changed then it is a `move`, otherwise it is an `update`. If many changes are done at the same time (one `save` on a context) the events will be delegated in the order - delete, insert, move, update.  The value of indexPath is the index before any inserts or deletes, and newIndexPath is the value after any inserts or deletes.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot!